# Accessing WSO2 IS-KM SOAP Endpoint in K8s cluster

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am deployed API Manager 3.1.0 and Identity Server as Key Manager version - 5.10.0 in kubernetes using GA release WSO2 docker images.
I had brought up 2 Active-Active instances of WSO2 API Manager and Identity Server as Key Manager and created cluster ip services to access those instances.
I had installed the NGINX Ingress Controller as NodePort service and exposed 443(https) port in order to access the cluster instances from outside(browser).
I has created the ingress rules for multiple host names to access the individual cluster ip services for api manager, api gateway and identity server
I had configured the hostnames in deployment.toml as the hostname given in ingress rules and transport.https.port as 443,so i am able to access the apimanager with url https://wso2apim/publisher because this url will land on ingress controller and internally controller will route to specfic clusterip service based on the provided hostname

Now I have to access the SOAP End Points of WSO2 Identity Server to configure some claims and for provisioning some default roles, when i will access the soap endpoint from outside the k8s cluster, I am able to access using ingress hostname eg. wso2is-km, but i want to access the soap end-point within the cluster, for that i have to use the clusterIP of identity server, I am able to access the cluster IP service, but the endpoint configured inside the SOAP WSDL file is ingress hostname on port 443, which i am not able to access within the cluster

Is there any way we can configure two different endpoints so that in SOAP WSDL we will have end point referring to clusterip service of identity server, or is there any way we can edit this generated wsdl for consumption...?